# IIS Block Request by X-Requested-With

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I want to block any requests if the header X-Requested-With does not contain word "ShockwaveFlash". I am very bard with pattern, could anyone help me with this? Here's what I've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_Requested_With}" pattern="^Shockwave$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```